# PS Alias command with output to .csv

Tags: powershell, exchange

Im trying to run an alias command and have it spit out the results into a .csv. Ive got the command to run, but unsure of the syntax to add the export command. Can someone assist with this?

The command I am using as:

```
get-mailbox | foreach{ 

 $host.UI.Write("Blue", $host.UI.RawUI.BackGroundColor, "`nUser Name: " + $_.DisplayName+"`n")

 for ($i=0;$i -lt $_.EmailAddresses.Count; $i++)
 {
    $address = $_.EmailAddresses[$i]

    $host.UI.Write("Blue", $host.UI.RawUI.BackGroundColor, $address.AddressString.ToString()+"`t")

    if ($address.IsPrimaryAddress)
    { 
        $host.UI.Write("Green", $host.UI.RawUI.BackGroundColor, "Primary Email Address`n")
    }
   else
   {
        $host.UI.Write("Green", $host.UI.RawUI.BackGroundColor, "Alias`n")
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: You should not be using `Write` commands if you want to send the output to a CSV; instead, return them as an array of objects, and then pipe the array to `Export-CSV`.

Comment: Or do both. Create to add to a collection for exporting later ***and*** write output seperately.

Comment: btw. In PowerShell I would suggest you to use the PowerShell way of writing output to host. e.g `Write-Host "Aliasn" -fore Green` instead of `$host.UI.Write("Green", $host.UI.RawUI.BackGroundColor, "Alias`n")`